# How to convert txt to binary files using DOCSIS with c#

Tags: c#, console-application, md5

I am converting a text file into binary file and pushing them on ftp server where DOCSIS is used to understand that binary file but unfortunately I am unable to do and getting the following error.

[image]

My code is following:

```
string binaryfileName = @"C:\TELNETAPP_Bilal\" + str+".bin";
        if (File.Exists(binaryfileName))
        {
            File.Delete(binaryfileName);
        }
        //BinaryWriter bwStream = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(binaryfileName, FileMode.Create));

        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
        //BinaryWriter bwEncoder = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(binaryfileName, FileMode.Create), ascii);

        using (BinaryWriter binWriter =
            new BinaryWriter(File.Open(binaryfileName, FileMode.Create), ascii))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < blines.Count; i++)
            {
                binWriter.Write(blines[i] + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit more complicated. You are trying to convert a human-readable text to the binary that is not understood by the cable modem. This is equivalent to writing C code to machine code.

I wrote a Java version of what you want and goes into detail on the process. You can piece together the Java code to C#

[OSCAR](https://github.com/Comcast/Oscar)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.